# submitting form from different view

Tags: php, forms, symfony, view, controller

this question may sound a bit newbie. What I am trying to do is to show a form inside a view, create an object and submit it.

My list view shows a list of existing objects and I showed a new/create button that brings the form which creates a new object calling the controller.

I don't know if there is a more proper way to do this but I came up with this code that works partially. The code works when my url is /new (showing only the form), however while it is /list it doesn't work.

List view (only relevant code):

```
{# AppBundle/Resources/views/list.html.twig #}

<div id="info">
    <button type="button" onClick="new()">New Object</button>
</div>

<script>
    function new() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", "/new", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

New view:

```
{# AppBundle/Resources/views/new.html.twig #}

{{ form(form) }}
```

Controller methods:

```
// AppBundle/Controller/ObjectController

public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $object = new Object();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($object)
        ->add('Text', 'textarea')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($object);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($object);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('list');
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));    
} 

public function listAction(Request $request)
{   
    $objects = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Object')
        ->findAll();
    return $this->render('AppBundle:list.html.twig', array(
            'objects' => $objects,
        ));    
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

No data are displayed in list.html.twig. You have to add this kind of code:

```
/.../
{% for object in objects %}
  {{ object.text }}
{% endfor %}

<div id="info">
    <button type="button" onClick="new()">New Object</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have that code just above but I omitted it. My problem is with the form. I replace the <div> block with the form and submit the new object. When I submit the object, the controller is called again with the object data and it is supose to redirect me after persisting my object, however the persistence never takes place. I guess this happens because of a wrong validation but I don't know the reason.

Comment: Do you want the same form display in list.html.twig? If it's the case, you have to give it to the view with your controller. `return $this->render('AppBundle:list.html.twig', array('objects' => $objects, 'form' => $form->createView())); ` Naturally, you have to build it by the same way used in `newAction()`.  I really don't understand the goal of this fonctionnality.

Comment: The goal is to create new objects without leaving the list view. I really don't know if there is another way to do it. I'd like to know what is the proper way to do it.